# Why is Python list.remove() not working properly?

Tags: python, list, filter

I have some lists of strings and I'm trying to find the most repeated value for each one of them. For doing so, I recreated a function whose input is the desired list; however, many of those lists contain the following element `'\\N'`. (two backlash and a capital N)

I don't want to take into account that element when the function search for the most repeated value, so I thought about filtering out said element from the list first and then run the function.

I tried using

```
NewList=List.remove('\\N')
```

to no avail. In fact, it deletes the whole list as I get nothing in return, using `len(NewList)` prints an error saying that it has no length. I thought that the element may be at fault, but I tried removing another string from the `List` and the same thing happened.

What's going on? is there a better way to filter out that element from the list?
Thank You

Comment: `List.remove()` doesn't return a new list, it modifies the list in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `list.remove`, it removes *one* matching item from the list, and returns `None`.

```
>>> my_list = ['foo', '\\N', 'bar', '\\N', 'ola']
>>> my_list.remove('\\N')
>>> my_list
['foo', 'bar', '\\N', 'ola']
>>> my_list.remove('\\N')
>>> my_list
['foo', 'bar', 'ola']
```

If you want to create a new list rather than modifying the existing list, consider using a list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = ['foo', '\\N', 'bar', '\\N', 'ola']
>>> new_list = [i for i in my_list if i != '\\N']
>>> new_list
['foo', 'bar', 'ola']
```

Comment: Even if you want to modify the existing `list` in-place, if you want to remove *all* copies of the item rather than just one (`list.remove` only removes the first copy found), you may want the listcomp, you'd just assign to the complete slice of `my_list`, e.g. `my_list[:] = [x for x in my_list if x != '\\N']`. That does build a new `list`, but it immediately extracts the contents to replace the contents of the original, then discards the temporary.